# How do I link files in a Codeigniter4 instance?

Tags: html, css, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter4, and I am serving an html file. In this html file, I want to reference a css style sheet. I am doing it like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/assets/css/style.css">
```

I have verified that there is a style.css file in public/assets/css/style.css. When I try to run this html file, I get a 404 error. Am I doing it wrong?

When inspecting the network tab of Chrome's developer pane, I find that it is trying to load it from the following directory:http://localhost:8080/public/assets/css/style.css

Comment: usually, `public` is root of site. if so, link should be `href="/assets/css/style.css"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these three methods.

Use `link_tag`

```
echo link_tag('public/assets/css/style.css');
```

Or normal way

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

or

```
echo base_url('public/assets/css/style.css');
```

---

> **Make sure `base_url()` is set in config.php `$config['base_url'] = "https://stackoverflow.com//";`**